# Objeto array dá erro quando tento acessar um elemento dele

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

```
package br.com.cursoemvideo;

public class Olho {
    private String cor;
    private boolean funciona;

    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }
    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    public Boolean getFunciona() {
        return funciona;
    }
    public void setFunciona(Boolean funciona) {
        this.funciona = funciona;
    }
    public Olho(String cor, Boolean funciona) {
        this.cor = cor;
        this.funciona = funciona;
    }

    public void verificar() {
        System.out.println("A cor do olho é: " +this.getCor());
        System.out.println("O olho funciona ? " +this.getFunciona());
    }
}
```

Classe do programa principal:

```
 package br.com.cursoemvideo;

    public class Aula_test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Olho[] ol = new Olho[1];

            ol[0] = new Olho("Castanho",true);
            ol[1] = new Olho("Azul",false);

            ol[0].verificar();
        }

    }
```

E aparece o erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>     at br.com.cursoemvideo.Aula_test.main(Aula_test.java:9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você declarou o *array* com capacidade para um elemento, aí tentou preencher 2 elementos. O segundo dá erro.

Talvez você esteja pensando que o 1 ali na declaração do *array* indica qual é o último elemento, mas não é, ele indica quantos são. ali não é o índice do *array*, o índice é usado só na última linha quando acessa o elemento (poderia acessar o elemento 1 também). Então se quer 2 elementos precisa usar 2 na declaração.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Olho[] ol = new Olho[2];
        ol[0] = new Olho("Castanho", true);
        ol[1] = new Olho("Azul", false);
        ol[0].verificar();
    }
}

class Olho {
    private String cor;
    private boolean funciona;
    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }
    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    public Boolean getFunciona() {
        return funciona;
    }
    public void setFunciona(Boolean funciona) {
        this.funciona = funciona;
    }
    public Olho(String cor, Boolean funciona) {
        this.cor = cor;
        this.funciona = funciona;
    }
    public void verificar() {
        System.out.println("A cor do olho é: " + getCor());
        System.out.println("O olho funciona ? " + getFunciona());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/d8U7wd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ArrayLimitjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/ArrayLimit.java).

Comment: Funcionou, mas agora me confundi. Fiz um curso online em que o professor fala que o vetor começa na posição 0. Então pensei que se eu quisesse um vetor com 2 elementos ele teria que ter o índice 1 (sendo a contagem 0,1)

Comment: Foi o que eu falei (eu percebi que estava confundindo com índice), ali você não está colocando um índice, está colocando quantos elementos deve caber nesse *array*, são coisas distintas.

Comment: Verdade, agora entendi. Obrigado !

Answer (score 2):

**Solução:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Olho[] ol = new Olho[2];

        ol[0] = new Olho("Castanho",true);
        ol[1] = new Olho("Azul",false);

        ol[0].verificar();
    }
```

Perceba que no código que você passou, está declarando um array de apenas uma única posição `new Olho[1]`, e ao mesmo tempo você tenta preencher duas posições pra ele, logo o erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>   at br.com.cursoemvideo.Aula_test.main(Aula_test.java:9)

Perceba que a própria mensagem de erro, já indica o problema, apenas lendo, já diz que na **thread main** possui um erro relacionado a um **array com indice fora dos limites** na **linha 9**